# How to make my pages in flutter persistent?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to make all my inherited pages persistent using flutter but I don't know how does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by persistent? do you want to preserve state over navigation, or through app closing, or something else?

Comment: As in perserve it's state

Comment: read [Docs > Cookbook > Persistence](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence)

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that this cannot be answered properly without seeing your implementation, here is what a lot of developers do:

1. If you application is simple, [store each state as a key-value pair](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value). Then store that value and key inside shared preferences.

You would simply need to:

1. Add `shared_preferences: "<newest version>"` to `pubspec.yaml`
2. Synchronously update the key-value pair in-memory using `prefs.setInt('currentState', value);`. This **persists** the data to the disk.
3. Read your state data suing `final counter = prefs.getInt('currentState') ?? 0;` and accordingly update your `setState` method:

Now, this does infact assume that you have a simple application with simple states. If you have more complicated states and actions, then you should consider things like the `BLOC` pattern in order to organize your app in a way that enables a larger amount of control.